# NSProgressIndicator on Modal Sheet Doesn't Animate

Tags: cocoa, modal-dialog, nsprogressindicator

My main window controller has a toolbar item that triggers the presentation of a modal sheet. The sheet is supposed to display the progress of a lengthy, asynchronous process (e.g., sync local data with a server).

However, I can not get the (indeterminate) progress indicator to animate.

This is the action that triggers the modal sheet:

```
var syncProgressWindowController: SyncProgressWindowController!

// ...

@IBAction func syncWithServer(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    // (Actual HTTP code not implemented)

    syncProgressWindowController = SyncProgressWindowController()
    syncProgressWindowController.loadWindow()

    guard let modalWindow = syncProgressWindowController.window else {
        return
    }

    self.window?.beginSheet(modalWindow, completionHandler: { (response) in
        // THIS GETS EXECUTED. 
        // However, the code below has no effect:   

        self.syncProgressWindowController.progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)

        // self.syncProgressWindowController.progressIndicator is 
        // NOT nil, despite windowDidLoad() not being called
        // (see below)
    })
}
```

The modal sheet window controller (class `SyncProgressWindowController` above) is defined like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var progressIndicator: NSProgressIndicator!


convenience init() {
    self.init(windowNibName: "SyncProgressWindow")
}

override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    // Breakpoints here don't work, logs don't print to the console.
    // Not called? But outlet _is_ set (see above).
}
```

The xib file (SyncProgressWindow.xib) has:

- File's Owner Identity/Class set to "SyncProgressWindowController"
- Window has New Referencing Outlet to File's Owner's `window`
- Window has `delegate` outlet wired to "File's Owner" (just in case - but delegate methods don't seem to get called either).
- Window has "Visible at Launch" unchecked (and is therefore displayed modally with no problems).
- Progress has New Referencing Outlet wired to File's Owner's `progressIndicator`.

**However:**

1. `SyncProgressWindowController`'s `windowDidLoad()` does *not* get called (Execution does not stop at breakpoints there and logs aren't printed).
2. Despite that, the property/outlet `progressIndicator` is set somehow, because the app does not crash when I attempt to animate it, with code like this:
       `self.syncProgressWindowController.progressIndicator.startAnimation(self)`

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

completionHandler will be fired when you close sheet by [endSheet(_:returnCode:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nswindow/1419497-endsheet) So you start indicator before sheet will be closed.

I'm not good in xib files, but when i disabled row with `loadWindow`, windowDidLoad was called. I'm not sure it's right way.

Comment: I thought that too about the completion handler. However, a breakpoint placed inside it stops execution just as the sheet is displayed (I did not code for dismissal yet). Attempting to animate the progress indicator at any other opportunity fails too, as I described in my question. Now I checked again, and it isn't being called... must have missed something.

Comment: Regarding `loadWindow()`, I think I put it there trying to get the modal presentation to work. You are right that removing it causes `windowDidLoad()` to be called, and now I can start the progress animation there. Thanks!